# Is the distinction between phoneme and allophone useful in language learning?

Tags: pronunciation, phonemes, allophones

IPA purpose seems straightforward to me: map all the known ways to produce sounds using the mouth to symbols and, for a specific language standard/dialect, map the possible sounds of it to these symbols. Now it is possible to describe the pronunciation of any word of the language/dialect in written form.

However, teachers, dictionaries and phonetic descriptions often uses phonemic transcriptions. As each phonem may be rendered by different allophones, the whole original purpose of IPA is broken IMHO.

Example 1: why use /paɪ/ instead of [pʰaɪ] to describe the pronunciation of the word "pie"? How would a Spanish native know that the initial "p" should be aspirated (Spanish has no aspirated "p")? The same applies for the flap T / D in GA English.

Example 2: GA American phonology Wikipedia shows /ɑ/ (open *back* unrounded vowel) as a *central* vowel in its vowel trapezoid diagram. Why not use the allophone [ä] instead, making clearer which is the standard sound?

The distinction between phonems and allophones may be useful in linguistics discussions, but I really do not understand its usefulness in language learning. It seems to me it only adds an extra layer of complexity and ambiguity.

Comment: I think we need some clarity from you about what exactly you want to teach Spanish speakers about English pronunciation.  Maybe you won't care whether they aspirate p's in exactly the way native English speakers do -- in that case, don't teach them that.  If you do want them to know about when to aspirate, you have to give them some information about it, don't you?

Comment: Shortest answer: because evidence shows that native speakers think in terms of phonemes, not phones.

Comment: @Greg Lee, I'd like to teach them how to aspirate like English speakers only once and afterwards they will know if a "p" in any new word is aspirated or not just by reading the IPA transcription in the dictionary. Doesn't that make sense? By the way, that was just an example.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that IPA is used only for phonetic transciption, but it is also used for phonemic transcription. It can be used for broader or narrower transcription, as required.

Comment: I am not assuming that. I am questioning the usefulness of phonemic transcription to language learners. I learn languages for 20 years and it has only confused me all this time.

Comment: Yes, that's very clear.  So you;re not trying to teach your Spanish speakers the same control over aspiration that native English speakers have, since of course the latter do not need to look in the dictionary to find out whether to aspirate.  Provided you can teach your Spanish speakers how to make aspirates or non-aspirates at any position, which neither ordinary Spanish speakers nor English speakers know how to do, that might work, eventually.

Comment: Here, for your convenience, is Sapir's classic paper on phonemic perception: http://ksw.shoin.ac.jp/spaelti/classes/Grad_Ling_105/files/Sapir.pdf

Comment: @Greg Lee Thanks for the paper. That knowledge is really new to me! I must confess it goes against my common sense, but it  surely is an excellent argument to use phonemic transcription in language learning. Related off-topic: as I proposed in the comments of one of the questions, I see no harm of having both the phonem transcription and the most usual phonetic transcription(s) in dictionaries (as Wiktionary does in some entries).

Answer (score 2):

You say the original purpose is lost. I ask, what is the original purpose?

Evidence indicates that native speakers remember phonemes, not phones. That is, an English-speaker's mental representation of "pie" is something like `/paj/`; the aspiration isn't "stored" as part of the word. Instead, English-speakers just know (subconsciously) to aspirate voiceless stops in stressed onsets, as long as they don't come after `/s/`. (This varies by dialect: I aspirate even after `/s/`, for example.)

Most language-learning programs are based on the same principle. There's an enormous amount of phonetic information in any word, so it's far easier to learn by "compressing" it: remembering a set of phonemes for each word, and a set of rules to turn those into a phonetic realization.

Comment: He meant the original purpose of the IPA, I thought, and surely the IPA is a system of phonetic notation. I understand why dictionaries intended for native speakers strip out a level and repurpose it as a system of phonemic notation, but the question of whether this is helpful for language learners stands. I suspect User6726 is right on that, but I don't think it's a simple as saying that an English-speaker's mental representation is X, therefore X is what needs to be taught to someone learning English as a second language and therefore starting with a different set of mental representations.

Comment: It seems to me that native speakers remember words by their sounds (allophones), not any written form of it. The written representation in a dictionary is just a tool to understand the sound. I doubt anyone (native or non-native) memorizes that written representation, so IMHO it should prioritize precision over conciseness.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista, Then it seems to you wrong.  Native speakers do not remember words by their sounds -- instead, they remember words by their phonemes.  This is not necessarily a written representation to be found in a dictionary.  Languages with no dictionaries, and even those with no conventional written form at all, work the same.  It took a long time for linguists to figure this our -- around a century -- but now this view is almost universally held.  It is not surprising that you don't know about it, but now is the time to learn.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Categorical perception is an amazingly powerful force! Humans generally aren't even aware of allophones in their native language.

Comment: @Minty Surely the IPA's used the "phonemic principle" from the beginning (which is why e.g. there's a letter `ɧ` used for a Swedish phoneme but without any phonetic value of its own, or why taps and flaps are conflated just because no language makes a phonemic distinction between them)?

Comment: I don't know the history in that much detail, but it seems reasonable to go off the fact that it was devised by the international phonetic association and named the international phonetic alphabet. You're right of course that it can also be used for phonemic transcription - I was just trying to draw attention to what I think is a slight mismatch between Q and A. I think that's there regardless of the exact timeline. I'm at an intermediate level in an L3 in which aspirated and unaspirated p are different phonemes. While I have no difficulty hearing which is which, I will often misremember...

Comment: ... a new word as having unaspirated p when it actually has aspirated p, and vice versa. I also notice that native speakers of the same language (Thai) have a similar problem remembering which English words have a sh sound and which have a ch sound, which is because they perceive them as allophones of a single phoneme - so I think the question of how you help someone acquire a phonetic system that is at odds with one they have deeply internalised is well worth asking, and that may be too hasty to say that you just feed them what native speakers have internalised.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction between allophone and phoneme is useful, because allophonic rules are ones that can actually be taught as general rules, whereas morphophonemic rules (neutralizing rules) generally are taught as "you just have to memorize it". However, actually teaching the technical terminology and giving phonemicization exercises is pretty useless.

If you present data in phonetic transcriptions, rather than phonemic transcriptions along side practice with contextual variants, you make it so much harder to learn the morphology and orthography of the language. The extent to which that actually matters depends on the language: aspiration alternations in English are not ubiquitous.

If you don't teach something like a rule of aspiration, then you will have to give phonetically transcribed data, which will confuse students into thinking that English is like Hindi; and you *will* have to explain why you get aspiration variation between appʰly vs. application. As for the symbol for the low back vowel, I suppose you do have to deal with Wikipedia which is likely to be a popular source of misinformation. There is no reason to transcribe that vowel as anything other than [a]. Most linguists don't truly understand the IPA, much less general language learners.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says that the [relevant table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American#/media/File%3AGeneral_American_monophthong_chart.svg) is from Wells 1982. It might be outdated, or based on controversial principles, or Wikipedia editors might have miscopied it—but I don't think it can be right to call John Wells "misinformed" about the principles of the IPA, given that he has been a member of the Council of the IPA since 1970.

Comment: <ɑ> is well established as a symbol for North American LOT/PALM in linguistics literature, EFL dictionaries, etc. probably because it was the symbol for RP PALM. Using <a> instead now runs the risk of confusing learners because it is now often used for RP/Canadian TRAP. Also it is my understanding that the *cot-caught* merger often results in a low back vowel.

Comment: I do not understand why phonetic transcriptions would make English students think that English is like Hindi. Regarding apply/application, I have never even realized there was difference regarding aspiration between both before. I am not sure I *have to* teach the aspiration rules, but even if I do, having a phonetic transcription would reinforce the rules. Whether learning by phonetic transcription is harder and confuses students, it is subjective IMHO. I as language student think the opposite. An alternative would be to include both in a dictionary.

Comment: "Most linguists don't truly understand the IPA, much less general language learners." How can linguists who explore sounds for a language not understand IPA?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Students, and you probably too, shouldn't think that English were like Hindi, where the difference is phonemic.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I must be missing something: you say "Whether learning by phonetic transcription is harder and confuses students, it is subjective IMHO", but isn't that pretty much the core of your question? Is that saying your question can only be answered subjectively, and you already know what the "correct" answer is for you? Why ask then?

Comment: But I suspect there would be *several* (possibly very many if I know Wiki editors) narrow transcriptions... combine all the possible dialects with all the possible levels of narrowness people may come up with. Even phonemic transcriptions aren't necessarily unique because they sometimes differ between British and American English, or simply because of different phonemic analyses (although I think Wikipedia, and probably Wiktionary, have a standard for that). But with phonetic transcriptions, I'd expect that to become the biggest section in an individual dictionary entry.

Comment: @LjL, that's a good point. Although I still hold my opinion, I respect the different arguments and opinions presented here. Maybe the best would be, as I mentioned above, to include both phonemic and phonetic transcriptions in dictionaries, as Wiktionary already does for GA English in words like "butter" and "article" (even if the phonetic translation misses sometimes some details, eg the aspirated B, at least it already transcripts the flap T). In that way, each person may use the transcription which he/she considers more useful.

Comment: @LjL if you keep only the most usual pronunciations, complexity should not be a issue. That's what Wiktionary does and I consider it very good. Again, I do not think there is one single right answer to the matter, but pros and cons of each option.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like "the most usual pronunciations" with a language like English where each dialect treats vowels and diphthongs differently. A narrow transcription takes those differences into account, and so unless one wanted to give, say, RP and General American special status (I can see the wiki flamewars with that...), it would be a jungle. You'd also have to specify the exact dialect next to every transcription. Really, I see *this* as a pretty compelling argument to provide phonemic transcriptions.

Comment: Sorry if it is a naive question, but what is the problem of focusing on GA and RP? Cambridge dictionary already does is, doesn't it? In my layman's ears, it approaches very well what I hear from *most* US and England natives, the English native speakers I have more contact with.

Comment: There us no aspiration in *apply* as opposed to *application* as neither has any aspiration!!!

Answer (score 0):

Broad transcription is meant to capture the difference between e.g. *dead*, *deed*, *lad*, *lead* "plumbum" and *lead* "guide, head" or whether *ghoti* is to be read as "fish". That can help a beginner, but no kind of transcription can help learning a perfect pronounciation. Have you taken a look at narrow transcription? It's a mess, and only useful for advanced linguists beginning to learn something new.

In short, **native English listeners hardly even perceive the difference** betwen e.g. /pʰɪt/ and /spɪn/, and if they do, they won't care much.

Otherwise, even if they noticed a foreign accent, the foreigner would need an introduction to phonetics, and a trainer to get rid of it. That would be too extensive to belong in a dictionary, or in an elementary class room.

A different dialect is noted differently in the respective dicts, which take a choice to note the allophone specifically, to present only one still mighty broad dialect--consider e.g. *dance* as the prime example for the difference between UK or US. You might ask why they don't note the aspirated labial plosive, too, but you'd have to make a case why they should. They have to limit the detail at some point. The prior answeres have already tried to point out that it is a reasonable decision.

Whether dictionaries noting narrow transcription of certain dialects exist and who should use them is a related, but different question. It rather seems that native *speaker* experience is required. Otherwise rule based descriptions are applied to broad description to yield a narrow dialect description, and the rules are inferred from example sets. The rules may differ depending on what is used as basis. So e.g. Spanish speakers necessarily build on Spanish. In principle, any learner tries to infer these rules, and only the important ones are noted in introductory classes.

Comment: Is *allograph* a proper word? Or is spelling reasonably standardized everywhere that it is not needed?

Comment: _Allograph_ is indeed a proper word. Examples of allographs are **a** and **ɑ**, which are allographs of the grapheme **<A>**. There are also lexemes and morphemes, not to mention phonesthemes like [`KL-`](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).